# Docker not running dist folder

Tags: docker

I'm trying to make a container of my builded angular app.

I have already build my app. so inside actual folder I have

dist/ src/ and root files

Here's my docker folder

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

built is ok

> docker build -t ngapp:1.0.9 .

```
Step 1/5 : FROM node:alpine AS builder
 ---> 2d8f48ba52b1
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d8d0d9d93f72
Step 3/5 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87c12f8c2ccf
Step 4/5 : FROM nginx:alpine
 ---> 36189e6707f4
Step 5/5 : COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e39f00401242
Successfully built e39f00401242
```

I run my app

> sudo docker run -p 8956:8080 ngapp:1.0.9

But when I go on the web page adresse the site is not running I get message : `this site is not accessible`

Comment: It looks like you've exposed nginx on port 8956, but you don't appear to be including that port in the URL I see in your browser. Additionally, nginx runs on port 80 in the container, but you seem to have mapped port 8956 to port 8080.

Comment: Sorry the url is just an example , I trigger the adresse XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8944

Comment: That still doesn't match the port you're publishing on your `docker run` command line.

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't have any sense, you don't build anything, you just copy files from one context to another. You are also publishing invalid port, you are supposed to publish the container's `80` port, not `8080`.

Comment: The Dockerfile looks fine. It adds files to `/usr/share/nginx.html` in a base nginx image. The use of a multi-stage build seems pointless, but it's not broken.

Comment: It's front end app , and I have already build it on local, as I know nginx needs only the dist folder content. When I run container in attached mode, I don't get any  logs when I visit the url

Comment: So you don't need the node image at all. You can copy directly to the nginx image. Still, the port is invalid, should be `8956:80` not `8080`. Nginx doesn't listen on this port by default.

Comment: that's it ! struggling since 24h ! you make my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nginx` container doesn't listen on port 8080 (by default), so simply map to the valid port:

```
ports:
    - 8956:80
```